# flask app gives 404 for non-root route

Tags: python, flask

I want to give flask a try. Using flask 0.12, python 3.4
I've created the project tree similar like in:
https://damyanon.net/post/flask-series-structure/

controllers.py code:

```
from flask import Blueprint
import functools, operator

main = Blueprint('main', __name__)

@main.route('/')
def index():
  return "Main world"

@main.route('/foo')
def foo():
  return "this is foo"
```

when I run the app,
I got 404 for /foo route but '/' is OK

```
    * Serving Flask app "run"
    * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
    127.0.0.1 - - [27/Dec/2017 15:19:21] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    127.0.0.1 - - [27/Dec/2017 15:19:25] "GET /foo HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Any clue?
Thanks.

edit:
As requested, here how I register *blueprint* in
flask_app/localservice/**init**.py. Not sure about *application* *factory*. I'm still new with this. I substitute *bookshelf* with *localservice* and not use *admin*

```
from flask import Flask
from localservice.main.controllers import main
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(main, url_prefix='/')
```

Comment: show us how you did register the `blueprint` and the `application factory` thing.

Answer (score 0):

I was following the same tutorial and the same error occurred for me as well. After being stuck on this for quite a while I finally figured it out.

So looks like there's an error in the tutorial. You can't register using '/'.
`app.register_blueprint(main, url_prefix='/')`

This is the actual [github codebase](https://github.com/damyanbogoev/flask-bookshelf/blob/master/bookshelf/__init__.py#L76) where the tutorial guy wrote the code.

If you look at the code and commit history, he changed `url_prefix` from '/' to 'main'. Change your `url_prefix` and the code should work.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't insist on following that tutorial, the code in the Flask Quickstart docs works perfectly fine

```
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Main world"


@app.route('/foo')
def foo():
    return "this is foo"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: the code from this tutorial works just fine too. they should provide more information so we could understand what's happening.

Comment: Well, you're right. Just a little over the top imho.

Comment: @EvyatarMeged I just want the code to be more maintainable in the near future, avoiding one file for everything. So,need some guide to start with project structure.